# Accessing parent scope variable inside nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive declared inside another directive, which should use a single variable from parent scope. This is what the structure looks like:

MAIN CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Settings){
$scope.userName = "";
$scope.init = function(){
 Settings.getUser()
                .then(function (res) {
                    $scope.userName = res.data.userName;
                    console.dir(res);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    //showError(err.data)
                });
};
}
```

main.html

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->

        <header></header>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->


        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->

            <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 561px;">

                <div ui-view></div>

            </div>
            <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
```

header.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
<header-notification user-name="{{userName}}"></header-notification>
</nav>
```

header-notification.js

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('headerNotification', function (Settings, $ngBootbox) {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'userName': '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                console.log($scope.userName);
            }],
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.userName);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am not able to access the value, I have also tried `scope.$watch` but still getting `undefined` in value..

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 changes you will need to make

1. Angular JS is not very good with camelcase. For some reason it inconsistently does not recognize/bind them. So, I would use "**username**"
2. remove the brackets when passing the variable. So, instead of `{{username}}` use just `username`
3. the variable name (**userName** - please change this to "username" as well)  you have used in directive does not match what you have in the header.html (**user-Name**)

Hope this solves the problem.